# Real examples of using EF lazy loading in MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lazy-loading

Can anyone post correct and useful an example of using EF lazy loading in MVC application?

I've tried to research the question, but I can't get proper case.

As a result my conclusion is: since web apps are stateless there is no sense to include LL to entities. But it sounds strange. That's why the question is here.

Can you confirm or otherwise refute my conclusion?

**EDIT**

The statment "stateless" in question context is important in my mind. Let's pretend 2 scenarios. First one relates for example to WPF app and the second one to MVC. Let's suppose that thre is the next simple object:

```
public class Person 
{ 
    public int Age { get; set; } 
    public string Name { get; set; } 
    ... 
    public virtual List<Activity> Activities { get; set; } 
}
```

1) WPF. User is able to request the only Person without his Activities. Thus he get a small portion of data. Overhead are reasonable. At the same time user can decide to request person's activities. 
Due to ll mechanism, EF simply loads activities without requesting person object again, since Person still exists in application (of course, if we code it in such a way).

2) MVC. The same actions are there. But the only difference that, after server response, all resources including object Person are disposes. And we can't load Person activities as we did in WPF application. We are forced to load Person again (overhead is increases comparing with WPF app)

The point is that Lazy loading can be executed only in the scope of the context to which the entity is attached - if you dispose the context you cannot use it.

Comment: refer this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/652556/Can-you-explain-Lazy-Loading

Comment: Could you carefully read the question? Your link doesn't answer it at all. I'm aware what lazy loading is, but I'd like to know is there any justified scenario of using it in web apps.

Comment: Refer this article : https://auth0.com/blog/12-steps-to-a-faster-web-app/

Comment: Heh, I don't think you get question correctly. I'd like to understand whether lazy loading of entities through EF can be properly used within asp.net mvc application or it is preferable to use eager loading always. How your article can help me in the subject?

Comment: I think you don't read both articles,  1st article told you how to use Lazy loading in MVC application via EF and 2nd article told you why we need to use the Lazy Loading and how can improve our web application by using many tips incl. Lazy loading. How can you say these articles are beyond your subject. Please carefully read both articles first then discuss what point are off topic. But Read first...  hope this clear to you. thanks

Comment: @sunilkumar, I've followed your links and read articles fully. 1) "1st article told you how to use Lazy loading in MVC application via EF". Some code from article: "Console.WriteLine(o1.OrderNumber);". Are you really thinking that it is MVC? 2) "2nd article told you why..." this article is about lazy loading in react js. Some code from there: <LazyLoad height={762} offsetVertical={300}> </LazyLoad>. So, I'm sorry, but I can't find any useful there. :-( –

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you understand what lazy loading does, as it has nothing to do with whether there's any state or not. It's not like caching or something. Lazy loading is simply Entity Framework overloading a property to add a custom getter that issues a query to fetch the object or set of objects when the property is accessed for the first time.

For example, if you had something like:

```
public class Foo 
{
    public virtual Bar Bar { get; set; }
}
```

And you were to query a set of `Foo`s from the database, the `Bar` property on all of them would be null, as EF would not have issued any queries yet to fetch the related `Bar` instance. However, if you were to iterate over this list of `Foo` and access some property on `Bar` (i.e. `foo.Bar.Baz`, then EF would issue a just-in-time query for the `Bar` instance, so that it could then return the `Baz` property on it.

Comment: Could you take a look at EDIT section in question?
Hopefully, you will get my point of vision. Thank you in advance!

Comment: I think he means the stateless-ness of the web and the fact that each request is going to instantiate the controller and corresponding ef context.

Comment: @fran, Yes, man. You got it. Let's post your thoughts about answer a question) Thanks)

Comment: @Fran: Got that. However, it still has no bearing on any of this. Any lazy-loading would happen within the same request and context instance as the original query. A new request would necessitate a new context and a new query (lazy loading or not).

Comment: @ChrisPratt exactly.  but since the lifetime is so short, does lazy loading make sense.  the exact answer is "it depends on what you're doing," but in most cases you don't want to lazy load because that can bring up n+1 select issues.  you can eager load everything you know you need and populate a view model to satisfy the request.

Comment: @Fran: Again, the choice to lazy load or not has absolutely nothing to do with the lifetime, short or not. Lazy loading is not caching. It boils down merely to whether you want to issue one big query, fetching data you may or may not ever use, or several smaller query, on an as-needed basis, but in either case, everything happens in the same request.

Comment: @ChrisPratt I know what lazy loading is.  yes, everything happens in the same http request to the page.  the lazy loading is going to happen in separate requests to the db.  so what i'm say is that in most scenarios when we are grabbing data for a web page.  it is going to be more efficient to write an eager loading linq query than is to iterate across child collections.

Comment: @Fran: I've the same thoughts. That's why I'm looking for an appropriate example with lazy loading. For now without result... :-(

Comment: @Fran: That was never in contention. Except for some off-the-wall scenario where you might iterate over a collection and only access the related property on one of the items for some reason, for example, it's always going to be more efficient to eager-load.